# postgres substring split text using regex

Tags: postgresql, substring

I am having following string pattern and I want to split the text into 4 fields.

`NIFTY21JUN11100CE` --> `NIFTY, 21JUN, 11100, CE`

In above string, only 2 string formats are constant. For ex: 21JUN represents year and month and it is constant 5 character representation. Before that represent name which can be any number of characters. I think regex will be like `(([1-2][0-9]))(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)`

last 2 characters are constant and its value can be either `PE|CE`. value between 21JUN and `CE|PE` represent strike price and it is always numeric but can be any number of digits.

Now I want them to be split into 4 fields and struggling to get the regex. Is anyone familiar with Postgres command for this requirement?

Comment: ` SELECT regexp_match('NIFTY21JUN11100CE','^(\D+)(\d{2})(\w{3})(\d+)(PE|CE)$');`

Comment: @clamp I think your RE is a littler aggressive as it returns 5 fields instead of 4. The section "(\d{2})(\w{3})" should just be (\d{2}\w{3}).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Clamp and Belayer. Yes, I was able to get that into 4 fields into array and use them further in the query. Cheers.

Comment: @Belayer you are right of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `SELECT regexp_match('NIFTY21JUN11100CE','^(\D+)(\d{2}[A-Z]{3})(\d+)(PE|CE)$');`

Step by step:

```
^          Beginning of the string
(          start capture
\D+        more than zero non-digit chars
)          end capture
(          start capture
\d{2}      exactly 2 digits
[A-Z]{3}   exactly 3 chars in the range from A to Z
)          end capture
(          start capture
\d+        more than zero digit chars
)          end capture
(          start capture
PE|CE      one of 'PE' or 'CE'
)          end capture
$          end of the string
```

The year-month regexes from your question using character classes `[1-2][0-9]` and alternations `(JAN|FEB|...)` are a little bit more strict and could also be used.